# nativescript sidekick cloud build fails to execute firebase hooks

Tags: ios, firebase, nativescript, nativescript-sidekick

I'm using `nativescript-plugin-firebase` on my ios app. I can't use nativescript-sidekick cloud build. It gives me this strange error and I don't really have any idea how to deal with this:

```
[20-02-06 01:33:31.307] (CLI)     + 553 hidden modules
[20-02-06 01:33:31.307] (CLI) Webpack compilation complete.
[20-02-06 01:33:33.357] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: /private/tmp/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.0/App/platforms/ios/.pluginfirebaseinfo not found, forcing prepare!
[20-02-06 01:33:33.357] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: running release build or change in environment detected, forcing prepare!
[20-02-06 01:33:33.357] (CLI) nativescript-plugin-firebase: /private/tmp/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.0/App/app/App_Resources/iOS/GoogleService-Info.plist does not exist. Please follow the installation instructions from the documentation
[20-02-06 01:33:33.357] (CLI) undefined
[20-02-06 01:33:33.357] (CLI) Failed to execute hook: /private/tmp/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.0/App/hooks/before-checkForChanges/firebase-copy-google-services.js.
[20-02-06 01:33:35.895] (CLI) undefined
[20-02-06 01:33:35.895] (CLI) Failed to execute hook: /private/tmp/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.0/App/hooks/before-checkForChanges/firebase-copy-google-services.js.
[20-02-06 01:33:46.312] Build step completed.
[20-02-06 01:33:46.316] Build failed. Build failed. Reason is: 'Build failed with error code 2'. Additional information: [00:01:25.681] [WARN]  undefined
[00:01:25.687] [WARN]  Failed to execute hook: /private/tmp/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.0/App/hooks/before-checkForChanges/firebase-copy-google-services.js.
[00:01:27.076] [ERROR] undefined
Failed to execute hook: /private/tmp/builds/_/228b3241ee6b0e8e978a529a92f93dabc2c54d59/6.3.3/6.3.0/App/hooks/before-checkForChanges/firebase-copy-google-services.js.
'Build failed with error code 2'.
```

How should I go about debugging this?

Comment: Hae you added your `google-services.json` and `GoogleService-Info.plist` files in the related resources directories? https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/nativescript-plugin-firebase#prerequisites